# Detecting change of status in a time series

Tags: sql

I have a table in which all the records have an id, timestamp, and a Boolean value. I need to discover in which records the Boolean changes to false within 1 second of it being true for the same id.

I've been working on the following statement, but after doing some research, I feel either a CASE combined with a FETCH statement might work better, but I haven't found a good example where they've been used together.

```
SELECT *  
FROM Table_1  
WHERE timestamp IN(  
    SELECT DATEADD(Second, 1, timestamp)  
    from Table_1  
    where Boolean = 1)  
AND ID in (  
    SELECT ID   
    from Table_1 where Boolean = 1)  
AND Boolean = 0
```

Comment: FETCH is a T-SQL command which allows you to get the next row from a cursor. It has nothing to do with standard SQL. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152.aspx.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @Mellonjollie Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Select Distinct
  t1.id
From
  Table_1 t1
    Inner Join
  Table_1 t2
    On
      t1.Id = t2.Id And 
      t1.Boolean = True And 
      t2.Boolean = False And
      DateDiff(Second, t1.Timestamp, t2.Timestamp) Between 0 And 1
```

a matter of taste as to how much of that you put in the join clause and how much you put into a where clause.

Edits

- added distinct
- put minimum bound on date difference

Comment: I think I see where you're going with that statement, however it's returning over 1 million rows when the table itself is only 107,000.

Comment: I've put a distinct in there now

Comment: Eureka, I got it! Thanks for the help Laurence.

Comment: I think you need to select those rows where DATEDIFF is not only less or equal than 1, but also *equal or greater than 0*. Otherwise you might get extra ID's where the difference is less than 1 second, because it's negative.